# Spring Integration - immediate response to be sent with asynchronous processing in background with http request handling messaging gateway

Tags: spring-integration

We have a requirement where the client are calling one of our spring integration http inbound gateway , the input given to the API is in .csv format and once the 
request is validated and found correct immediate response should be sent with status 200 OK. In case of an error appropriate error message is send . 
We use a combination of direct and  executor channel for asynchronous processing. This works fine when using spring boot parent version 1.2.5 but fails when upgraded to 1.4.0 version.We always get a 500 Internal server error with cause as found from logs is MessageTimeoutException.

We are using java based configuration and the configuration is below.

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

@Configuration
public class ApplicationIntegrationConfig {    

    @Bean
    public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpMessageGateway(){
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway
                = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(Boolean.TRUE);
        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/org/{orgId}/users");
        requestMapping.setHeaders("Content-Type=text/csv");
        gateway.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);
        gateway.setRequestChannel(onBoardUserRequestChannel());
        Map<String, Expression> customHeaderExpressions = new HashMap<>();
        customHeaderExpressions.put("orgId", new SpelExpressionParser().
                parseExpression("#pathVariables.orgId"));
        gateway.setHeaderExpressions(customHeaderExpressions);
        gateway.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());
        gateway.setReplyTimeout(0);
        return gateway;
    }    

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel processUserRequestChannel() {
        DirectChannel channel =new DirectChannel();
        channel.addInterceptor(new AuthenticationInterceptor());
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel routeChannel() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel addUserChannel() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel removeUserChannel() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }    
}
```

**Splitter**

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class PartnerUserOnBoardSplitter {     

    @Splitter(inputChannel= "processUserRequestChannel", outputChannel="routeChannel")
    public List<UserDTO> split(Message message) throws ApplicationException {
        List<UserDTO> userList = null;
        try {
            userList = validateAndCreateDTO(message);
        } 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new ApplicationException("<Message>");
        }
        return userList;
    }    
}
```

**Router**

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class CustomRouter {

    @Router(inputChannel="routeChannel")
    public String resolveRoute(UserDTO dto) {
        return (Operation.ADD.equals(dto.getOperation())) ? "addUserChannel" : "removeUserChannel";
    }    
}

public class ServiceActivator{

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "addUserChannel")
public addUser(UserDto dto){
//process add
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "removeUserChannel")
public removeUser(UserDto dto){
//process remove
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an enhancement/improvement to Spring Integration 4.2 [JIRA here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3781).

Previously, if a reply was expected and timed out, the user incorrectly got a 200 OK. Now he gets a 500 with a timeout exception.

Since you are configuring the gateway to expect a reply, this is triggering this feature.

Simply configure the gateway to not expect a reply...

```
HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway
            = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(false);
```

You will also see faster responses because the container thread will not wait for a reply that will never come (default timeout is 1 second).

**EDIT**

If you sometimes want to send a reply and not at other times, set `expectReply` to true and add this configuration:

```
gateway.setStatusCodeExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("200"));
gateway.setReplyTimeout(0);
```

I [added some javadocs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/56b9b2401ebfa2cc4ff8ccadad4f934050e762d7) - hope that helps.

For those using XML configuration, it's...

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                      path="/receiveGateway"
                      reply-timeout="0"
                      reply-timeout-status-code-expression="200"
                      supported-methods="POST"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how will i return and error message if the input is invalid .If we configure the gateway to not expect a reply then even the error messages are not sent.  I expect to reply 200 OK once the validation passes and the processing is expected to continue in the background else throw an error message back to the caller